# Can't capture data in rewrite rule

Tags: apache, url, mod-rewrite

I'm trying to capture data in this rule but it doesn't work

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /blog/
RewriteRule ^blog/a/(.*)/(.*)/?$ index.php?a=1$&b=2$ [NC]
```

but the other rule is working

```
RewriteRule ^blog/(.*)/?$ default.php?a=1$ [NC]
```

Please what am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Is the **RewriteBase /blog/** in the right directory to the file you are rewriting to

Comment: yes it is other rules are working

Comment: There is no problem with your rule, if this is not the exact rule you have in your ```.htaccess``` file please cross check the string carefully if there is no typo or a / at the beginning of the rule